# AS2 to AS3 .swf

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-3, swf

Имеется *.swf* проект с **AS2**, но мне необходимо *сконвертировать* в **AS3**

Как это можно реализовать?

Из исходников только сам проект, открытый в *Flash Decompiler Trillix*.

Comment: Очень сильно отличается платформа. Скорее всего никак. Принцып построения и связывания там другой.

Comment: @nick_n_a
Будет очень печально. И да, не знаете в чем можно .swf открыть, чтобы скомпилировать в AS3, если возможно? Быть может в Flash Decompiler'e есть такая функция?

Comment: Если проэкт скомпилирован в as2 то декомпиляция даст результат as2 однозначно.

Comment: @nick_n_a
Ну что ж, и на том спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно знать оба языка программирования: active script 2.0 и active script 3.0.
Берете исходный код и вручную его переписываете на active script 3.0. Другого варианта нет. По затратам времени - это будет столько же, если не больше, как написать всё с нуля.